# Alguien sabe como convertir una imagen original a blanco y negro; tmabien como aplicar textura de haralik con OPENCV y java (no C++)

Tags: java, android

alguien tiene información de como convertir una imagen original a blanco y negro y también como aplicar textura de haralik a la imagen original?.

Añado codigo(para que me deje publicar la pegunta);en caso les sirva a alguien:

```
public void EcualizacionHistogramaOPENCV(){
    Mat sourceMat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, sourceMat);

    Mat destinationMat = new Mat(sourceMat.size(), sourceMat.type());
    Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceMat, sourceMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    Imgproc.equalizeHist(sourceMat, destinationMat);

    Bitmap equalizerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMat.cols(), sourceMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(destinationMat, equalizerBitmap);

    //show equalized image
    imgviewecualizacion.setImageBitmap(equalizerBitmap);
    GuardarEcualizacion();
}

private Bitmap bitmapFromImageView(){
    return ((BitmapDrawable)imgviewtomarfoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: El código es el que actualmente usas para tratar de convertir la imagen a Blanco y Negro?

Comment: Puedes obtener los pixeles del bitmap con un for, Otra forma seria con open gl. Para agregar textura dibuja usando canvas si puedes o con opengl, creo q grafika github hay un ejemplo de video black and white, si lo tiene puedes usar su shaders.

Comment: EL codigo es ecualización de histograma y busco como poner en blanco y negro  y textura de haralik con OPENCV en android puro